# Oracle SQL unique constraint A to B, B to A

Tags: sql, oracle

my table is something like

```
FROM   TO     DISTANCE              
------ ---- ---------- 
A      B    100  
B      C    100
Z      A    120
```

i need to add a constraint to the table that won't let insert
`B A 100` or `C B 100` or `A Z 120`

i have a `PRIMARY KEY (from, to)` and `CONSTRAINT const_u UNIQUE (to, from)` but it doesn't work as expected.

EDIT:
I also cannot force alphabetically correct order on insert, as i don't have access to the insert logic 
EDIT#2: Can you add B A 50 ? -- no, you can't. There should be only one unique distance from A to B or B to A but not both at the same time.

Comment: I would recommend creating a trigger and chk for matching paris

Comment: i can't create a trigger. i have to solve the problem another way.

Comment: Can you add `B A 50` ?

Comment: The reason why the unique constraint and pk dont work is that, they both fire independently, if you already have a record as A,B the pk wont let you insert A,B again (which is fine) and then there's a unique constraint as (to, from), so now if you try to insert B,A, the unique constraint shall allow this as no record as B,A exits (the only one that exists is A,B (which is dis-allowed by the pk))

Comment: ok, i know this. so what's the solution? :)

Comment: The only solution I am aware of is using triggers to achieve this !!

Comment: Can you add B A 50 ? -- no, you can't. There should be only one unique distance from `A to B` or `B to A` but not both at the same time.

Comment: i'm not allowed to use triggers. that's my main problem :)

Comment: one table with two primary keys not possible. you can make one field primary and other field with unique key constraint.

Comment: @zeal, I would go with BellevueBob answer

Comment: so there is no constraint for this kind of problem in oracle sql? no check constraint, or anything like that? i've also tried to do embedded query in a check constraint but it's against the syntax

Comment: possible duplicate of [Oracle cyclic foreign key references issues](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1739890/oracle-cyclic-foreign-key-references-issues)

Comment: @Akash Triggers won't allow checking for duplicates, MVCC would allow statements to independently add (A, B) and (B, A) at the same time. Depending on the ins and outs, you could use a trigger to change the order so if (B, A) is used to change it to (A, B) then put the unique key on those two columns. I like a_horse_with_no_name's answer better than that trigger solution.

Comment: @APC why do you think my question has anything to do with foreign keys?

Comment: The possible duplicate question ([Oracle cyclic foreign key references](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1739890/oracle-cyclic-foreign-key-references-issues)) is not a good match for an 'exact duplicate'.

Comment: The fact that the question I suggest as a duplicate deals with foreign keys rather than primary keys is irrelevant.  The man thing is it is it concerns enforcing uniqueness of *combinations* not *permutations*, just like this question.

Comment: Anyways, i just don't see the point of setting this Q as a duplicate. The question you've marked deals with totally different problem...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
create unique index on the_table (least(from,to), greatest(from,to));
```

Will prevent adding (B,A,100) if (A,B,100) is already in the table.

Comment: `create unique index index_name on the_table (least(from,to), greatest(from,to));` works like charm, thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

If you are willing to make this a rule, you might try a `CHECK` constraint:

```
CONSTRAINT force_collation CHECK (FROM < TO)
```

Comment: it's good for a specific case, but if i want to save `Z A 100` it will fail although `A Z 100`is not in the table...

Comment: But you could still save A Z 100, no?  That's why he said "if you are willing to make this a rule".

Comment: yes, but i can't force the alphabetical order on inserting values!

Comment: You might be able to enforce this rule in your ETL process using a CASE expression.  It really depends on how you are loading your table.

Comment: it's still not the solution.