# UNIQUE CONSTRAINT: Enforcing a unique list or set of columns

Tags: sql, unique-constraint

Given:

```
create table list(a bigint not null, b bigint not null);
insert into list(a, b) values(1, 1);
insert into list(a, b) values(1, 2);
insert into list(a, b) values(2, 1);
insert into list(a, b) values(1, 2);
```

How do I implement the following constraints?

1. Prevent a duplicate list of values. Example: (1, 2) conflicts with (1, 2).
2. Prevent a duplicate set of values. Example: (1, 2) conflicts with (2, 1).
3. Does SQL UNIQUE constraint apply to a list of values (where order matters) or a set of values (where order is ignored)?

**UPDATE**: I am looking for a database-agnostic answer. If that's not possible, a database-specific answer is acceptable.

Guys, **please post answers if you're answering the question.** Comments are reserved for asking questions about the question.

Comment: What RDMBS are you using?

Comment: Btw: this has been asked before: http://stackoverflow.com/q/15731227/330315

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The third question is simple, "yes".  Uniqueness is based on the ordering of the columns (list of values in the question).

The first item listed can be handled by a unique constraint (or equivalents a unique index).

You can handle the second item with a trick, which is available in many databases.  A check constraint can verify that `a` < `b`.  In combination, this will guarantee both (1) and (2).

To make the "check" method more palatable, you can add a "before insert" trigger.  This trigger will swap the values, so `a` is the smallest.

You can also check for the condition in triggers (although the syntax for triggers differs a bit among databases).

Those are the general rules.

Different databases then offer different levels of functionality.  For instance, Oracle supports functional indexes, so you could explicitly have a unique index on the least of a and b and the greatest of a and b -- voila, a constraint exactly as you want it.  SQL Server offers computed columns, which you can persist.  You can include these in a unique constraint.

Comment: Good answer except I think you misunderstood #3. I was asking if SQL UNIQUE was checking uniqueness based on a list of values vs a set of values. Therefore, I believe the answer is "list of values". Is that correct?

Comment: @Gili . . . It takes the ordering into account, which is what you are calling a list of values.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your DBMS you can create a unique index like this:

```
create unique index idx_ab on list(greatest(a,b), least(a,b));
```

(This should work at least on Postgres, Oracle and DB2 if I'm not mistaken)

SQLFiddle example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/5add4/1

Comment: +1 for the creative solution but this is a partial answer (you've ignored questions #1 and #3). Thanks anyway :)

Comment: @Gili: that **will** cover #1

Comment: Brevity is nice and all, but in this case I would appreciate a more elaborate explanation. If this will cover #1 you should say so explicitly and you've still neglected to answer #3.

Comment: @Gili: Gordon has already answered #3, why should I repeat the answer?

Comment: I thought you were trying to get your answer marked as accepted in place of Gordon. Sorry for the confusion :) Thanks again for your answer!